# Abstraction layer over an ObjectMapper decorator: how do I approach deserialization of generic types?

Tags: java, design-patterns, jackson, abstraction

I decorated an `ObjectMapper` and provided an additional abstraction layer to avoid coupling with `ObjectMapper` directly. Take a look:

```java
class ClientServerCommunicator {
    private static final Serializer serializer = new JacksonSerializer();
    // more code
```

```java
public interface Serializer {
    String serialize(Object object);
    <T> T deserialize(String serializedObject, Class<T> clazz);
}
```

```java
public class JacksonSerializer implements Serializer {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    public String serialize(Object object) {
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
    }

    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    public <T> T deserialize(String serializedObject, Class<T> clazz) {
        return objectMapper.readValue(serializedObject, clazz);
    }
    @SneakyThrows
    // not present in the interface!
    public <T> T deserialize(String serializedObject, TypeReference<T> typeReference) {
        return objectMapper.readValue(serializedObject, typeReference);
    }
}
```

However, when it comes to deserialization of generic types, I'm not sure how I should describe it in my interface. So far, I simply cast to `JacksonSerializer` which will fail if I decide to use another implementation

```java
        ServerSocketMessage<ChatAuthentication> serverResponse = ((JacksonSerializer) serializer).deserialize(line, new TypeReference<>() {
        });
```

Should I add an additional abstraction layer for `TypedReference`? What if other libraries handle it differently (they don't pass some generic dummy)?

What would you recommend?

Comment: related: [The Rule of Three](https://andrewbrookins.com/technology/the-rule-of-three/) and [The Wrong Abstraction](https://sandimetz.com/blog/2016/1/20/the-wrong-abstraction)

Comment: @jaco0646 I understand what you mean. However, I'm still curious what the solution is